# Re request the URLs or URL from parse() in python scrapy manually

Tags: python, python-2.7, request, scrapy, python-requests

I have simple script that scrape data from amazon you all know there is a captcha so when captcha arrives the page title is 'Robot check' so i have written logic for this situation if page `title = 'Robot check'` and print message ' page not be scraped there is captcha code on the page' and do not get data from this page. otherwise continue script.

But in the if part I have tried `yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse)` for re request the current URL but I got no success. I Just have to do is re request the `response.url` again and continue the script as it is for that i think i have to do is delete the `response.url` from log file so scrapy do not remember URL as scraped simple i have to fool the scrapy and request again same URL or may be if there is way to mark `response.url` as failed url so scrapy automatically re request.

Here is the simple script and `start_urls` is in separate file named urls in same folder so i have imported it from urls file

```
import scrapy
import re
from urls import start_urls

class AmazondataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazondata'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk']
    def start_requests(self):
        for x in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(x, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            if 'Robot Check' == str(response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first().encode('utf-8')):
                print '\n\n\n The ROBOT CHeCK Page This link is reopening......\n\n\n'
                print 'URL : ',response.url,'\n\n'
                yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse)
            else:
                print '\n\nThere is a data in this page no robot check or captcha\n\n'
                pgtitle = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
                print '\n\n\nhello', pgtitle,'\n\n\n'
                if pgtitle == 'Robot check:
                    # LOGIC FOR GET DATA BY XPATH on RESPONSE
        except Exception as e:
            print '\n\n\n\n',e,'\n\n\n\n\n'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell Scrapy to not to filter out duplicate links, because, by default Scrapy does not visit a link if its already visited and have received `200` http_status.

Do [`dont_filter=True`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request)

In your case,

```
print '\n\n\n The ROBOT CHeCK Page This link is reopening......\n\n\n'
print 'URL : ',response.url,'\n\n'
yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```